# How to bypass the Clipboard while transposing

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, transpose

I am trying to speed up code that copies a lot of data amount a lot of spreadsheets.  The problem is that I need to copy a range that goes down a row to a range that goes down a column.

I have tried setting the ranges equal to each other, which doesn't work.  I also set the calculation setting to manual. That sped it up some but not as much as I wanted.

This is the current code that I have in the macro

`CFFile.Sheets(CFTabName).Range("B" & RowIndex & ":CW" & RowIndex).Copy`

`SubmissionFile.Sheets(TargScenTabName).Range(ColumnIndex & "4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True`

I have tried this code

```
SubmissionFile.Sheets(TargScenTabName).Range(ColumnIndex & "4").Value = CFFile.Sheets(CFTabName).Range("B" & RowIndex & ":CW" & RowIndex).Value
```

No error, but it takes about 2.5 minutes per file to complete.

Here is the giant ugly code that it is a part of

```
`Sub TranInsRiskCF()

Dim StartTime, EndTime As Double
StartTime = Now()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Const BOB_INDICATOR = ".xlsx"
Const DOLE_INDICATOR = ".xlsm"

Dim FileName As String
Dim TargTemplatePath As String
Dim CFFolderPath As String
Dim SubmissionFolderPath As String
Dim CFFilePath As String
Dim CFUnit As String
Dim CFDate As String
Dim CFIdentifier As String
Dim CFBOBOrDogTag As String
Dim TargScenTabName As String
Dim CFTabName As String
Dim ColumnIndex As String

Dim UnitRow As Integer
Dim ScenRow As Integer
Dim TabNameRow As Integer
Dim RowIndex As Integer
Dim CFScenNum As Integer

Dim SubmissionFile As Workbook
Dim CFFile As Workbook
Dim ThisBook As Workbook
Dim SubmissionName As String

Set ThisBook = ActiveWorkbook
ThisBook.Sheets("Control").Activate

'Store Path Information

FileName = Range("B5").Value
TargTemplatePath = Range("B6").Value
CFFolderPath = Range("B7").Value
SubmissionFolderPath = Range("B8").Value

'Start Unit Processing

UnitRow = 12

Do While Range("A" & UnitRow).Value <> ""

    CFUnit = Right(Range("A" & UnitRow).Value, 3)
    CFDate = Range("B" & UnitRow).Value
    Sheets("Tables").Activate


    RowIndex = 2
    Do While (Range("A" & RowIndex).Value <> CFUnit)
        RowIndex = RowIndex + 1
    Loop

    CFIdentifier = Range("B" & RowIndex).Value
    CFBOBorDOGTag  = Range("E" & RowIndex).Value

    If CFBOBorDOGTag  = BOB_INDICATOR Then
        If Left(CFUnit, 2) = "00" Then
            CFFilePath = CFFolderPath & "\" & "CF_ILB_0" & Right(CFUnit, 1) & "T_" & CFIdentifier & "_" & CFDate & CFBOBorDOGTag 
        ElseIf Left(CFUnit, 1) = "0" Then
            CFFilePath = CFFolderPath & "\" & "CF_ILB_" & Right(CFUnit, 2) & "T_" & CFIdentifier & "_" & CFDate & CFBOBorDOGTag 
        Else
            CFFilePath = CFFolderPath & "\" & "CF_ILB_" & CFUnit & "T_" & CFIdentifier & "_" & CFDate & CFBOBorDOGTag 
        End If

    ElseIf CFBOBorDOGTag  = DOLE_INDICATOR Then
        If Left(CFUnit, 2) = "00" Then
            CFFilePath = CFFolderPath & "\" & "CF_ILB_0" & Right(CFUnit, 1) & "T_" & CFIdentifier & "_" & CFDate & CFBOBorDOGTag 
        ElseIf Left(CFUnit, 1) = "0" Then
            CFFilePath = CFFolderPath & "\" & "CF_ILB_" & Right(CFUnit, 2) & "T_" & CFIdentifier & "_" & CFDate & CFBOBorDOGTag 
        Else
            CFFilePath = CFFolderPath & "\" & "CF_ILB_" & CFUnit & "T_" & CFIdentifier & "_" & CFDate & CFBOBorDOGTag 
        End If
    End If

   If Len(Dir(SubmissionFolderPath & "\" & FileName & "ILB " & CFUnit & ".xlsm")) = 0 Then
        Set SubmissionFile = Workbooks.Open(TargTemplatePath, , ReadOnly:=False)
        SubmissionName = "IRM_CF_201906_Template.xlsm"
    Else
        Set SubmissionFile = Workbooks.Open(SubmissionFolderPath & "\" & FileName & "ILB " & CFUnit & ".xlsm", ReadOnly:=False)
        SubmissionName = FileName & "ILB " & CFUnit & ".xlsm"

    End If

    Set CFFile = Workbooks.Open(CFFilePath, , ReadOnly:=True)

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    'Start Scenario Processing

    ThisBook.Sheets("Control").Activate

    ScenRow = 12


    Do While Range("D" & ScenRow).Value <> ""
        TargScenTabName = Range("E" & ScenRow).Value
        CFScenNum = Range("D" & ScenRow).Value
        CFFile.Sheets("Market Risk CFs Output").Activate

        RowIndex = 3
        Do While (Range("A" & RowIndex).Value <> CFScenNum)
            RowIndex = RowIndex + 1
        Loop

        ThisBook.Sheets("Control").Activate

        TabNameRow = 12


            SubmissionFile.Unprotect Password:="cashflow1"
            SubmissionFile.Sheets(TargScenTabName).Visible = True
            SubmissionFile.Sheets(TargScenTabName).Unprotect Password:="cashflow1"


        Do While Range("G" & TabNameRow).Value <> ""
            CFTabName = Range("G" & TabNameRow).Value
            ColumnIndex = Range("H" & TabNameRow).Value
            CFFile.Sheets(CFTabName).Range("B" & RowIndex & ":CW" & RowIndex).Copy

            'SubmissionFile.Sheets(TargScenTabName).Range(ColumnIndex & "4").Value = CFFile.Sheets(CFTabName).Range("B" & RowIndex & ":CW" & RowIndex).Value

            SubmissionFile.Sheets(TargScenTabName).Range(ColumnIndex & "4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

            TabNameRow = TabNameRow + 1
        Loop

        ScenRow = ScenRow + 1


    Loop

    With SubmissionFile
        .Sheets(TargScenTabName).Protect Password:="cashflow1"
        .Sheets(TargScenTabName).Visible = False
    End With

    SubmissionFile.Sheets("Inputs").Activate
    Range("C5").Value = "Individual Life - Actuary"
    Range("C6").Value = "ILB " & CFUnit

    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

    'Application.Run "'" & SubmissionName & "'" & "!ThisWorkbook.unhidethesheet"
    SubmissionFile.Protect Password:="cashflow1"

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    SubmissionFile.SaveAs (SubmissionFolderPath & "\" & FileName & "ILB " & CFUnit)
    SubmissionFile.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    CFFile.Close False

'    SubmissionFile.Close

    UnitRow = UnitRow + 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Loop

EndTime = Now()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

MsgBox "Cash Flows Transferred." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
       "Run Time: " & Format(StartTime - EndTime, "hh:mm:ss")

End Sub`
```

Comment: Can you show the loop?  I assume you have an if in there or you would just transpose the whole range at once.

Comment: The code is pretty sizeable, and pretty ugly its something i picked up from m predecessor.  but i will add it to the above.

Comment: Then create a [mcve] that shows the issue so we can show you a better method.  But to speed it up the rule of thumb is to load everything in a variant array and loop that filling another variant array, then output that array in bulk to the worksheet.

Comment: Since the code could not be tested and is heavily dependent on the actual data, it is difficult to foresee any method to speed up its operation. However since it search (loop) for each values corresponding to each `CFUnit` and `CFScenNum` and assuming 100 Ks of rows involved in that search. these search times could be reduced considerably by using LastRow and [Range. Find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find). However before attempting the same may please check if considerable share of total time involved is consumed by these searches.